# AFNetworking : send asynchronous data mde "Post"

Tags: php, ios, post, afnetworking-2

Hello I try to use AFNetworking to register a user in the database from my server but it does not work.
Here are the IOS code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager POST:@"http://www.myWebSite.com/user/newUser" parameters:dictonaryUser success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
header('Content-type: text/json');
    echo json_encode($_POST);
```

Here the error :

```
2014-02-01 11:07:24.051 myApp[2534:70b] Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x8b9af60 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Can you show your JSON response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this code

```
AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;
```

and still if it's not working then refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874935/afnetworking-2-0-post-issue-cocoa-error-3840json-text-did-not-start-with-array)